# Display specific service under ShareThis button

Tags: social-network

I went through the configuration of ShareThis module but couldn't find any way to hide/disable services which aren't required.
In my case I am using the ShareThis button under "Selected Service"as per my site design. This button displays the list of all the available services but what if I just wanted to display few required services like Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Youtube & Whatsapp.
[image: Selected Service]

[image: Required Services]

Comment: Drupal version currently used ??

Comment: Drupal core 8.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ShareThis module which is too difficult to modify. I used AddToAny module which provides me with only the required services. To provide it a layout I created a twig file for the services block and add whatever HTML & Classes I wanted to use.

I displayed the services in a modal window.What I wrote in twig file:

```
{% block content %}
<div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal fade" id="modal-external-link" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Share
</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">  {{ content }} </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Before Somebody asks me why I didn't do it with ShareThis. I didn't because AddToAny is lightweight.